# Spring tries to bind form post parameters once for each model attribute

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller with the following:

```
@ModelAttribute("searchCriteria")
public abstract SearchableCommand searchCriteria();

@ModelAttribute("searchList")
public PaginatedListAdapter searchList() {
    return new PaginatedListAdapter(defaultSortColumn, searchableService);
}

@RequestMapping
public String doSearch(
        @ModelAttribute("searchCriteria") SearchableCommand searchableCommand, 
        Errors errors,
        @RequestParam(value="sort", required=false) String sort, 
        @RequestParam(value="pageSize", required=false) Integer pageSize, 
        @RequestParam(value="dir", required=false) String dir, 
        @RequestParam(value="page", required=false) Integer page, 
        @ModelAttribute("searchList") PaginatedListAdapter searchList) {

    //some logic here
};
```

And in my JSP I have the following for test purpose:

```
<form:form id="searchForm" commandName="searchCriteria">
    <form:input path="searchCriteria[0].searchOperand"/>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit"/>
</form:form>
```

When submitting the form, I trace through my code and `searchableCommand.getSearchCriteria[0] .setSearchOperand(...)` is called correctly.  However once this is done I recieve the exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: Invalid property 'searchCriteria[0]' of bean class [com.domain.web.command.PaginatedListAdapter]: Cannot access indexed value of property referenced in indexed property path 'searchCriteria[0]': returned null
```

This because it is also trying to call `PaginatedListAdapter.getSearchCriteria[0] .setSearchOperand(...)`.  Co-incidentally this class also has a method called `getSearchCriteria`, but regardless it makes no sense to me as to why spring is trying the bind the form post parameters to both `@ModelAttribute` arguments, when my form explicitly states `commandName="searchCriteria` for which only one `@ModelAttribute` has that name.